# How to check if a webRTC peer has already have specific tracks assigned to it?

Tags: webrtc, simple-peer

I am trying to understand if there is a way to know if a peer has already been hooked up with a specific audio and/or video track or not because before `peer.addTrack(track)` I want to make sure a track will not be added twice to the same peer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try removing that track before adding, if you suspect a duplicate:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/removeTrack

Or check track senders for duplicates:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getSenders

PS: Usually there's 2 track events that are not duplicates (audio + video).

Comment: Actually since I have multiple tracks I cannot remove a track I just need to make sure if it is added or not.